# How do I select an extra row for each row in the result set in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query:

```
SELECT '['+name+']' FROM sys.schemas
Where name <> 'dbo' AND name <> 'guest' AND name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
....
```

The result of this query is simple:

[image]

I need an extra row with text 'GO' after every record like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I tried with a `foreach` statement, but I was unable to replicate the desired results.

Comment: It is better to write `SELECT QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.schemas ...`.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz It hit me when i read Gordon Linoff answer.!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want carriage returns and "GO" after each line, you can put that in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT '[' + name + ']
GO'
FROM sys.schemas 
Where name <> 'dbo' AND name <> 'guest' AND name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' 
....
```

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but it might do what you need.

Comment: This one is simpler than all other answers.

Answer (score 24):

Just add Go statement to the Dynamic code by hitting ENTER key and  see the result pasting in SSMS. This will populate with `GO` statement in Next line.

You should also use QUOTENAME rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself (to work correctly for names containing `]`) and the where clause can be simplified with `NOT IN`.

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(name) +'
GO
' 
FROM sys.schemas 
WHERE name NOT IN  ('dbo', 'guest', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
```

Comment: OP had clearly mentioned `I need is extra row with text 'GO' after every record `, do take some time to read the question. This answer  won't do what OP wants.

Comment: At the End OP needs to execute the dynamic statements. In-fact he asked to add new record. But intention is to divide it in a batch. Suggesting a correct way is not a bad idea.@JibinBalachandran

Comment: I have read all question and I understood that he need to split the result in a batch statement. when this small solution doing the work why he need to go for Complex solution. Hope you understand my thought to suggest him, @JibinBalachandran

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Ok,Sorry.. I was wrong.I apologize for that. +1 from my side.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it by using `UNION ALL` to populate these extra values, and the use `CASE EXPRESSION` in the `ORDER BY` clause for this specific order:

```
SELECT t.name_col
FROM(
    SELECT '['+name+']' as name_col,'['+name+']' as ord_col
    FROM sys.schemas 
    Where name NOT IN('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'GO','['+name+']' as ord_col 
    FROM sys.schemas 
    Where name NOT IN('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA')) t
ORDER BY t.ord_col,
         CASE WHEN t.name_col = 'GO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: The `ORDER BY` is needed so the `GO` rows are interleaved.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks for the answer.!

Answer (score 6):

```
select  c.txt
from    sys.schemas cross apply (values ('['+name+']'),('GO')) c(txt)
where   name not in ('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
```

---

Guaranteed order

```
select      c.txt
from        sys.schemas s cross apply (values ('['+name+']',1),('GO',2)) c(txt,ord)
where       s.name not in ('dbo','guest','INFORMATION_SCHEMA') 
order by    s.name,c.ord
```

Comment: you may have to specify order like Sagi did

Comment: I'm currently not near a computer but I assume CROSS APPLY would not requier a sort

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Yep. As expected, no sort is needed

Comment: sort is not guaranteed in final output

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz *not near a computer* >> You can surf to http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler to quickly test your statements.

Comment: @TT. - Apparently you don't have the same cellphone as I :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way with cross apply values

```
SELECT B.*
FROM   (SELECT '[' + NAME + ']' AS NAME1,
               'GO'             AS GO1
        FROM   SYS.SCHEMAS
        WHERE  NAME NOT IN ( 'DBO', 'GUEST', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA' ))A
       CROSS APPLY ( VALUES(NAME1),
                           (GO1) ) B(NAME1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Newline explicitely inside the column:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME(name)+CHAR(10)+CHAR(13)+'GO' 
FROM sys.schemas 
WHERE name <> 'dbo' AND name <> 'guest' AND name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA';
```

Newline in a new row:

```
SELECT
    lot
FROM
    (
        SELECT name=CAST(QUOTENAME(name) AS VARCHAR(256)),extra_line=CAST('GO' AS VARCHAR(256))
        FROM sys.schemas
        WHERE name <> 'dbo' AND name <> 'guest' AND name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
    ) as p
    UNPIVOT(lot FOR l IN (name,extra_line)) AS up;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
select name from (
SELECT 2 * rowid as r, 
    '['+name+']' as name
    FROM sys.schemas 
union
select 2 * rowid + 1, 'GO' FROM sys.schemas 
)s
order by r
```

Comment: My answer used sqlite syntax, referring to 'rowid', which is the row number.  That might not be available in whatever dialect of SQL you are using (but you could create a temporary table with your own generated row number, and use my method; it works)  In any case, @ahmed abdelqader: with your edit, changing 'rowid' to 'schema_id', my answer is now not just incompatible, but meaningless; with your change, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ahmed abdelqader: I have undone your edit; please see preceding comment.

Comment: This is essentially the same technique used by @sagi's answer; but that answer is more complete, and uses the same SQL dialect as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `CONCAT` also instead of `+` for `SQL2008+`

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', name ,'] GO ')
FROM sys.schemas 
WHERE name <> 'dbo' AND name <> 'guest' AND name <> 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA';
```